# How to use predicate search using Mongodb C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How does one use the following Method on the awesome MongoDB c# Driver!????

```
public IList<TEntity>SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
            {
                return collection
                    .AsQueryable<TEntity>()
                        .Where(predicate.Compile())
                            .ToList();
            }
```

Examples would be ideal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the `Compile` because that creates a `delegate` that the driver can't translate into a mongo query:

```
public IList<TEntity>SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return collection
        .AsQueryable<TEntity>()
            .Where(predicate)
                .ToList();
}
```

It does however means that the *predicate* expression must be translatable by the `MongoDB` driver.

Comment: Ok.  Can you give me an example of how to use it though?

Comment: @ENC0D3D it depends on what your TEntity is, but here: `SearchFor(hamster => hamster.Name == "Bar")`

Comment: I tried that but it returns 0 records. With and without the compile... `IList<tickets> lstTickets = _ticketRepository.SearchFor(x => x.description == search);`

Comment: Why wouldn't it? do you have a hamster named bar?

Comment: @ENC0D3D i don't really get what you want.